# Find rows where is null applicant_id in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, null

I need to find **null applicant_id by web_user_id** after the min(date) where applicant_id was first filled

For example, for web_user_id 23 we will find null applicant_id after the row_id = 3, because it is first filled applicant_id with min(date)

For web_user_id 90 we will find null applicant_id after row_id = 11, because it is first filled applicant_id with min(date)

https://prnt.sc/264ofhg

the table is:

```
| row_id  | applicant_id  | web_user_id  | date  |
| ------- | ------------- | ------------- | ---- |
| 1       | null          | 23            | 2020 |
| 2       | null          | 23            | 2021 |
| 3       | 77            | 23            | 2022 |
| 4       | 77            | 23            | 2023 |
| 5       | 77            | 23            | 2024 |
| 6       | null          | 23            | 2025 |
| 7       | 77            | 23            | 2026 |
| 8       | null          | 23            | 2027 |
| 9       | 77            | 23            | 2028 |
| 10      | null          | 90            | 2020 |
| 11      | 55            | 90            | 2021 |
| 12      | 55            | 90            | 2022 |
| 13      | 55            | 90            | 2023 |
| 14      | 55            | 90            | 2024 |
| 15      | null          | 90            | 2025 |
| 16      | 55            | 90            | 2026 |
| 17      | 55            | 90            | 2027 |
```

the condition is:
**select min(date), applicant_id, row_id, web_user_id**
and after this date I need to find rows where applicant_id is null

As a result I would to have this table:
https://prnt.sc/264om6u

```
| row_id  | applicant_id  | web_user_id   | date |
| ------- | ------------- | ------------- | ---- |
| 6       | null          | 23            | 2025 |
| 8       | null          | 23            | 2027 |
| 15      | null          | 90            | 2025 |
```

SQL for creating the table

```
create table dbo.tabl (
row_id int,
applicant_id int,
web_user_id int,
"date" int
);
```

```
insert into dbo.tabl values 
(1, null, 23, 2020),
(2, null, 23, 2021),
(3, 77, 23, 2022),
(4, 77, 23, 2023),
(5, 77, 23, 2024),
(6, null, 23, 2025),
(7, 77, 23, 2026),
(8, null, 23, 2027),
(9, 77, 23, 2028),
(10, null, 90, 2020),
(11, 55, 90, 2021),
(12, 55, 90, 2022),
(13, 55, 90, 2023),
(14, 55, 90, 2024),
(15, null, 90, 2025),
(16, 55, 90, 2026),
(17, 55, 90, 2027);
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your data and expected results in text instead of a link to an image?

Comment: 5 mins please!))

Comment: Can we assume that row_ID+1 of the min(Date) for each application_ID will always be the desired record?  or could there be a "Gap" beteen rows for different applicant_IDs? in which case we'd need to assign our own row_number() partitioned by application ID...  though I keep thinking cross  apply would work here...

Comment: @xQbert we need just do partition by web_user_id to find null applicant_id after the min(date) where applicant_id for this web_user was filled

Comment: @lptr Cool logic! Thank you!!  This is  what i meant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I tried and a simple query too. You can try this one too

```
   Select  applicant_id, row_id, web_user_id,min("date")
     from tabl 
     where applicant_id is null
     and "date" > 2024
     group by applicant_id, row_id, web_user_id,"date";
```

Comment: I added explanations, but this is not what I expected. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
**This request was written in a rush. But I think it will help you.**

Select *
from (Select *
      from (Select t.*,
                   LAG(applicant_id) OVER(PARTITION BY WEB_USER_ID ORDER BY 
t."date") LAG_,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.WEB_USER_ID Order BY 
t."date") RN
              from tabl_test t)
     where not (applicant_id is null and lag_ is null))
where applicant_id is null
```